# a preg_replace in wordpress stops at html tags

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, preg-replace

I have written a preg_replace in my functions.php for my wordpress blog for my girlfriend to use a "shortcode" like the following:

```
[spoiler id="1" show="show me the list" hide="hide the list"]test1
test2<ul>test3
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
</ul>
[/spoiler]
```

My preg_replace in the functions.php is the following:

```
function BUFU_add_spoilers ($content)
{   global $post;
    $pattern = "/\[spoiler id=\"(.*?)\" show=\"(.*?)\" hide=\"(.*?)\"\](.*?)\[\/spoiler\]/is";
    $replacement ='<br><div align="right" style="margin: -58px 0 0 0"><a id="button_show_%SPOILID%_$1" onclick="document.getElementById(\'spoiler_%SPOILID%_$1\').style.display=\'block\'; document.getElementById(\'button_hide_%SPOILID%_$1\').style.display=\'\'; document.getElementById(\'button_show_%SPOILID%_$1\').style.display=\'none\';"><h5>[$2]</h5></a></div><div align="right"><a id="button_hide_%SPOILID%_$1" style="display: none" onclick="document.getElementById(\'spoiler_%SPOILID%_$1\').style.display=\'none\'; document.getElementById(\'button_hide_%SPOILID%_$1\').style.display=\'none\'; document.getElementById(\'button_show_%SPOILID%_$1\').style.display=\'\';"><h5>[$3]</h5></a></div><span id="spoiler_%SPOILID%_$1" style="display: none" class="spoilerBox">$4</span>';
    $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
    $content = str_replace("%SPOILID%", $post->ID, $content);
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'BUFU_add_spoilers', 5);
```

All works just fine if there is only text in between the "shortcodes", but it somehow does not work for the example above. The spoiler will include everything up to the opening `"<ul>"` (or an opening `"<table>"` for that matter), so test1 and test2 are in the spoiler, test3 is NOT.
I just have no idea why. I tested the preg_replace online and it worked just fine.

I reckon it has something to do with the way wordpress adds filters and stuff to work on the text, but I can't figure it out...
The result is just an empty `... class="spoilerBox"></span>` followed by the list..

If anyone can help me with this, it would be greatly appreciated!
I'm really going nuts over this problem!

Thanks in advance,

BUFU

Comment: You should use the already present functionality for adding shortcodes (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode), instead of trying to recreate it.

Comment: Granted. I will look into that. Thank you for now! =)

Comment: Take a look at the example under `Example with enclosed content: [baztag]content[/baztag]`. You will not need regex at all. :)

Comment: Okay, I have to thank you for making me look more into writing your own shortcodes! I did it like it's supposed to be and now everything works just perfectly. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this:

Simply use shortcodes instead.

[wordpress reference for add_shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode)